# Jenkins 2.5 installation error (An error occurred during installation: Forbidden)

Tags: jenkins

I have a fresh CentOS box, installed Tomcat 8.0 and Jenkins 2.5. After entering the secret key for a brand new installation, the next step *Install* suggested plugins or :Select plugins to install:.  After clicking on *Install suggested plugins* I got an error saying

> An error occurred during installation: Forbidden

I assume is related to folder permissions, the question is which one?

UPDATE: The jenkins log says

> Found invalid crumb a711b93261896fb36a1d6ffbe163dca6.  Will check remaining parameters for a valid one...
>   May 21, 2016 4:19:34 AM WARNING hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter doFilter
>   No valid crumb was included in request for /jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test. Returning 403.*

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 36):

If it's any help to anybody, I "fixed it" by restarting Jenkins `http://jenkins:8080/restart`, or whatever protocol, domain, and port.  Then when I went back in it asked me for the secret key again, and then installed all the plugins successfully.

Comment: similar issue but in my case I had to execute `service jenkins restart` (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Restarting worked for me in Windows 7 also, thanks =)

Comment: Doesn't work on CentOS 6; I tried both http://localhost:8080/restart and service jenkins restart

Comment: Helped me too in CentOS environment. This issue has not occurred in Fedora environment

Comment: Worked in CentOS7.2

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this problem before. It was because I was using a **VPN**. Once I closed the VPN, everything returned back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error when I was using Internet Explorer for JENKINS INSTALLATION on Windows 2019. I installed Chrome before trying again and the error went away!

Comment: same with windows 2016

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue because I was using Internet Explorer. Switching the browser fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue, [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38931127/10907864) helped me.

**Here's some addition to it**:

I was running [Jenkins on docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins), so to restart it I had to do the following;

List all the running docker containers on the server:

```
docker container ls
```

Copy the container id for the Jenkins container

Restart the docker container for Jenkins using its id:

```
docker restart <jenkins-container-id>
```

Visit the URL for Jenkins again:

```
http://your-url:8080
```

Input your initial admin password, and then try setting up Jenkins again.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**